# How to notice symmetry?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

What is the easiest method to notice the symmetry of the following function without using any graphical tool: 
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{4-x^2}}$$

Comment: The fact that $x$ appears only as powers of $x^2$?

Comment: You may want to read about even and odd functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Definition_and_examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest is to note that
$$ f(-x) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{4 - (-x)^2}} = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{4 - x^2}} = f(x)$$
now if $x > 0$ then by the above we can see that for negative values of $x$ the function maps the same values as the positive side of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends only on $x^2$ so it gives the same value for every positive real $x$ and its negative. Such a function is called even.